# Best way to find/update duplicate people in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a process that imports CSV files containing "person" information from several vendors.  The process has to read the people from the CSV, and decide if the person needs to be inserted or updated in the database.

A person can actually exist in CSV of different vendors -- so I can't just look each person up by ID (each vendor would have a different id for their "people").  So, I have to determine if the person is new to the database by looking at:

1. Vendor Id + VendorAssignedID  (i.e. the id of the vendor being processed along with their unique person id)
2. SSN
3. Firstname + Lastname + Birthdate

If a match is found, I need to update the person with any changed information from the vendor CSV.  If no match is found, then the person needs to be inserted.

Each CSV may contain as many as 1000 people.  Each person has to be checked against the database to see if they need to be inserted or updated.  If the database contains 10,000+ people, it seems like this is going to be painfully slow with or without EF Core (potentially 10,000,000 reads per CSV).

I currently use EF Core in the project but in this particular area, it doesn't seem like EF Core is up to the task.

I'm curious how others have tackled this kind of issue?  What is my fastest option for doing something like this -- a series of `MERGE` statements, a stored proc called with EF Core?

**Additional Info**

Based on some of the answers, I thought I'd add the following.

First, the CSV files are in different formats -- different column names, different value types (iow, one vendor may use numbers to identify gender while another may use letters).

The CSV files are being uploaded to the server via a .Net Core Web API.  The Controller/Action parses the CSV file, converts values into a common format and creates a list of `Person` objects that hold the data.

So, in reality, the comparison is between the data in each `Person` object and the data in the database.

Comment: You're sort of going down a rabbit hole here. I worked at a company for 15 years, and they got my DOB wrong initially. A couple years later, I realized and put in for an update. So they changed it to a different wrong date. In some, but not all systems. Those got propagated to vendors. My DOB is now junk data. And, also, [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) talks about more blind alleys to run down. Just, know what you're getting into here.

Comment: Believe me, I know the pitfalls associated with trying to match people -- even SSN isn't foolproof.  However, sometimes you're mandated to settle for less than optimal solutions.

Comment: Fair statement. FWIW, since there will be several string comparisons going on, whatever you use is going to be pretty slow.

Comment: Agreed!  I probably should've stated it above, but I'm not assuming there will be any "blazing fast" solution for this -- what I'm trying to find is the fastest of my slow options. :-)

Comment: P.S. I'm a developer, not a DBA, so I'm by no means an expert in SQL.  Could just use some guidance from those that know SQL well, what my options are

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your CSV is fixed and known format as it will make thing a bit easier.

I would look at doing the import in stages:

1. You parse and ingest all your CSV lines into a `tblCsvImport` that does not have much constraints apart from CSV file name (id?) and whatever you can determine at that time. All columns will be nullable and no matching is done yet.
2. You run a stored proc that does [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) based on your rules and optionally purges the table when done

If your CSV format is somewhat flexible you might be looking at a bit more work as you'll have to store raw lines and parse them in the stored proc. Depending on your complexity a cursor over ingest table lines might be easier to implement (although bear in mind, cursors in SQL server come with a bit of a stigma for poor performance)

Answer (score 0):

If you're able, this would likely be the best performing option:

1. Do a [bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) of the csv file into a new table (or existing table if the schema doesn't change, if you retain the table, you'll want to truncate as your first step)
2. Write a [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doing the necessary insert/update (and delete if needed)
3. Drop (or truncate) the table from step 1